# Jenkins Android Lint Plugin , How to use it

Tags: android, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, lint, android-lint

It's my first to use stackoverflow........

Android Lint Plugin in Jenkins , I really don't know How to use it,PLZ help me

1.I kown I write "**/lint-results.xml" in Lint files,
but what is lint-results ? what I should write in this file?

2.How And Where can I check Android Lint result ?

Comment: I find answer by myself,this plugin,very very keng

Answer (score -2):

2.How And Where can I check Android Lint result ?

in Android Studio. you choose: Analyze -> In Spect Code -> Whole Project -> OK !!!